# VB Script cannot list all user access and permission from VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, vbscript, wmi, visualsvn-server

The VB script from my last question [VB script to retrieve Access Rights Reporting from Visual SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916380/vb-script-to-retreive-access-rights-reporting-from-visual-svn/23262243#23262243)

I have tested after upgrade to VisualSVN Server V.2.7.4 but it unable to list all repositories and user access due to following error in my cmd. Looking for some help!!

[image]

Comment: @bahrep looking for your help

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers looking for your help, hope you both see my question

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because some of your repositories has an invalid access rule applied, the script itself does not validate access rules in authorization files.

In order to solve the issue, you have to run the script again in order to determine what repository has the invalid access rule. Rules that are printed right before the error occurs can provide you with the clue about which repository has the invalid rule. Check
`/conf/VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini` file of the affected repository or use VisualSVN Server Manager to view it's access rules. One of the access rules won't resolve in VisualSVN Server Manager and you have to remove the access rule to solve the issue.

Path-based authorization relies on access rules configured in authorization files. When [Windows (Active Directory) authentication](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00039/) is used, access rules in authorization files look like this:

```
S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820-1013=rw
```

The first part is the SID (Security Identifier) of the user or group account for which the rule applies to. In your case, some SID has invalid format thus it's unresolvable. The issue is not caused by the fact that the SID is unresolvable but because the SID is completely invalid. Such issue can happen if someone modified authorization files manually (i.e. using a text editor).